# profiling and code coverage analysis with llvm/clang

Tags: xcode

I'd like to do some profiling and code coverage analysis on some C code.  From webpages like [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/SourceBasedCodeCoverage.html) and [here](http://cmdlinelinux.blogspot.com/2018/04/profiling-c-code-with-clang-using.html) I see that I probably need tools like `llvm-cov` and `llvm-profdata`.  But my Mac doesn't seem to have them.  Anybody know how to install them?

[P.S. I can see from the tag description on [xcode] that "Almost all questions about development or app distribution are off topic here".  I apologize in advance if mine is such a question.  If someone can point me to a better place to ask, or even to the FAQs which the tag description cites, I'll be grateful.]

Comment: Do you want to use the GNU/Clang tools (as explained in the links you provided) or do you want to use Xcode? In the second case, did you already look at the developer documentation on apple.com?

Comment: @nohillside Well, what I *want* to do is profile some code I've been compiling with `cc`.  I know that `cc` is really llvm/clang underneath, so I did a web search, and those links are what I came up with.  And, no, I didn't look at the developer documentation on apple.com — frankly I wouldn't know where to start!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Profiling can be done in Instruments, just build the release binary and run it via Instruments.app.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruments_(software)
- https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/11.4/#/devcc15e6912
- https://help.apple.com/instruments/mac/10.0/

For code coverage, Use Xcode's code coverage in Edit scheme -> Test -> Gather coverage for ...

- https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/11.4/#/dev9e0e09978

---

Xcode also contains llvm-profdata and llvm-cov in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin`. Put that in PATH and it should work normally.

---

If you *have* to use the llvm tools, either directly download from https://releases.llvm.org or use something like brew.

Here's how to make it work https://stackoverflow.com/a/63690216 with Xcode. If you just want to use terminal, simply changing SDKROOT and PATH is enough.

Comment: Thanks.  I should perhaps have said that I'm doing everything on the command line.  (I've never even heard of Instruments.)

Comment: @SteveSummit: Instruments is a powerful tool, so you should check it out. If you have a lot of overlapping/concurrent things to analyze, look into [signposts](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging/recording_performance_data) which Instruments can visualize.

Comment: @anki This almost worked.  It took a while (the package is big, and my home bandwidth is low, so it took several tries) but I got the llvm tools downloaded, and... they can't read the profile data files my instrumented code is generating, due to a version number mismatch in the profile data files.  Dang.  So now I'm downloading an older version...

Comment: Version 9 worked, and I've found a hotspot already.  Thanks again.

Comment: @SteveSummit see the update https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/436032/revisions